# Using Cheerio Js to select a particular element with same class

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

```
<div class='one'>THis is first div</div>
 <div class='one'>THis is the second div</div>
```

So I want to get the text inside these two divs one by one. So with each loop it only gets the current element of the div.

```
const searchResult = selector("div[class='one']")
    .each((index, element) => {
      let selection = selector(element);
      return selection.text();
    })
    .get(index);
```

So with each div with class="one", I want to return the text of that div only, above is my current code, but it doesn't seem to work, it seems that the `.get()` isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want map:

```
$(div.one).map((i, div) => $(div).text()).get()
```